# How can a pointer data type variable can contain an object?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qtcpsocket

I'm rather new to c++ / QT and i'm having hard time to understand a bunch of code from a TCP Socket tutorial (https://www.bogotobogo.com/Qt/Qt5_QTcpSocket_Signals_Slots.php).

This is the **mytcpsocket.h** file (class declaration) :

```
#ifndef MYTCPSOCKET_H
#define MYTCPSOCKET_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QAbstractSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class MyTcpSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTcpSocket(QObject *parent = 0);

    void doConnect();

signals:

public slots:
    void connected();
    void disconnected();
    void bytesWritten(qint64 bytes);
    void readyRead();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;

};

#endif // MYTCPSOCKET_H
```

So, there is a private attribute called "socket" which is pointer type in the class declaration.

This is the **mytcpsocket.cpp** file (class definition) :

```
// mytcpsocket.cpp

#include "mytcpsocket.h"

MyTcpSocket::MyTcpSocket(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void MyTcpSocket::doConnect()
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()),this, SLOT(disconnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(bytesWritten(qint64)),this, SLOT(bytesWritten(qint64)));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readyRead()));

    qDebug() << "connecting...";

    // this is not blocking call
    socket->connectToHost("google.com", 80);

    // we need to wait...
    if(!socket->waitForConnected(5000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << socket->errorString();
    }
}
```

You can see in the doConnect() method that it's initializing that "socket" attribute (which is a pointer, right?) with an object from the class QTcpSocket.

How is it possible ?
I mean, from what i've learned ;

```
int number{10};
int *ptr_number = &number
ptr_number // variable that store number's memory address.
*ptr_number = number // deferencing ptr_pointer.
```

So it should be :

```
*socket = new QTcpsocket(this);
```

Instead of :

```
socket = new QTcpsocket(this);
```

Here, "socket" should just contains a memory address, no ? How can we affect something to it ?

Plus, another small question ;
Why are we not using "this" keyword to initialize attributes in the class declaration ? :

```
this->socket = new QTcpsocket(this);
```

I apology if these questions might look a bit silly, but i can't find any good explanations around...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to read a good C++ book. `operator new` returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory.

Comment: When you write `socket`  `this->socket` is implicitly assumed.

Comment: Oh god ... It was as simple as this ! Thank you so much.

Comment: btw it is rare for beginners to get confused by thinking pointers are not the objects they point to (which is correct), it is more common to see confusion caused by thinking pointers are the objects (which is not correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator new` returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory.

Regarding `this->socket`, it's implicitly assumed and we can directly use `socket` variable.

Thank you @CinCout and @vahancho !